# Randomly occurs with Meteor: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalidate' of undefined"

Tags: meteor

On what seems to be random occasions, when a user on my website tries to answer a question on the quiz page, the following error occurs:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalidate' of undefined
at Tracker.Dependency.changed (tracker.js:388)
at ReactiveVar.set (reactive-var.js:82)
at null. (builtins.js:22)
at view.js:191
at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (template.js:437)
at view.js:190
at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (view.js:523)
at viewAutorun (view.js:189)
at Tracker.Computation._compute (tracker.js:294)
at Tracker.Computation._recompute (tracker.js:313)
```

I am unsure as to why this occurs, and I am not entirely sure when this error even means so if someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great!

Note: this error seems to only occur when using Chrome.

Comment: Use the given stack trace to find the root of the problem. Since we don't have the src from all of those files there isn't much we can do to help.

Answer (score 1):

I'll hazard a guess, here's the culprit code in [`Tracker.Dependency`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/tracker/tracker.js#L416)

```
Tracker.Dependency.prototype.changed = function () {
  var self = this;
  for (var id in self._dependentsById)
    // My Comment - we're expecting this to be a `Tracker.Computation` which has an `.invalidate()` method!
    self._dependentsById[id].invalidate();
};
```

So, the problem is that *something* is modifying `Object.prototype`.

eg.

```
Object.prototype.test = function(){}
var emptyObj = {}; 
for (i in emptyObj) 
  console.log('has key=', i, 'isOwnProperty?=', emptyObj.hasOwnProperty(i))
```

will print out:

```
has key= test isOwnProperty?= false
```

A possible solution to try, would be adding this snipped to the client, and seeing if it fixes the problem (At least temporarily):

```
Tracker.Dependency.prototype.changed = function () {
  var self = this;
  for (var id in self._dependentsById){
    if (self._dependentsById.hasOwnProperty(id)){
      self._dependentsById[id].invalidate();
    }
  }
};
Tracker.Dependency.prototype.hasDependents = function () {
  var self = this;
  for(var id in self._dependentsById)
    if (self._dependentsById.hasOwnProperty(id))
      return true;
  return false;
};
```

However - It's bad practice to add to `Object.prototype`, and lots of code will fail in unexpected ways. You'll need to track this down.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without more info, but I'd take a look here, specifically the part under "Subscriptions Don't Block":

https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes

As the author states, "In meteor, the majority of "Cannot read property of undefined"errors are caused by an incorrect assumption about the existence of subscribed data."

In other words, you may be trying to access the invalidate property before your subscriptions has returned anything.